# When do I discard a card for Skeleton Key?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Skeleton Key](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSkeleton%20Key%5d) states: "whenever equipped creature deals combat damage to a player you may draw a card. If you do, discard a card."

My question is - do you discard the card before you draw the card or do you get to see the drawn card before you discard?

Answer (score 6):

You draw the card first. You can even discard the card that you drew. In general, you always follow instructions in the order written on the card.

Interestingly, this doesn't appear to be specified in the basic rulebook or quick start guide. But here's the rule from the comprehensive rules for it:

> 608.2c The controller of the spell or ability follows its instructions in the order written. However, replacement effects may modify these actions [...]

Comment: @Gendolkari While the comprehensive rules are, well, *comprehensive*, I think it's not in the basic rulebook because it is fairly intuitive. I mean, what other order should you execute the instructions on a card? I think in this case it's quite clear that you draw first by the instructions: “If you do, [draw a card], discard a card.”

Answer (score 0):

To draw a card you have to put it in your hand.
While you have it in your hand, you see it.
From the game's point of view there's no in-between time when the card is no longer in your library but not yet in your hand.

So yes, you get to see the card before you perform the discard.